# Write the same function behaviour in redux reducer and actions

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I want to ask how to rewrite the same function behaviour using redux reducers and actions.

There is a function what I need to implement to redux

```
handleSelect = itemValue => {
    this.setState(
      {
        ...this.state,
        base: itemValue,
        result: null,
      },
      this.calculate,
    );
  };
```

First step what I did was creating a actionTypes.js and action.js files. 
Code below actionTypes.js

```
export const HANDLE_FIRST_SELECT = 'HANDLE_FIRST_SELECT';
```

and my action.js

```
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes';

export const handleFirstSelect = itemValue => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.HANDLE_FIRST_SELECT,
    itemValue: itemValue,
  };
};
```

In next step I created a reducer what look like this

```
import React from 'react';
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
  currencies: ['USD', 'AUD', 'SGD', 'PHP', 'EUR', 'PLN', 'GBP'],
  base: 'EUR',
  amount: '',
  convertTo: 'PLN',
  result: '',
  date: '',
};

const exchangeCurriences = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.HANDLE_FIRST_SELECT:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.itemValue]: state.base[action.itemValue],
        result: null,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default exchangeCurriences
```

next I created mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps functions in my container file like that

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    baseCurrency: state.base,
    amountPrice: state.amount,
    convertToPrice: state.convertTo,
    result: state.result,
    actualDate: state.date,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    handleFirstSelect: itemValue => dispatch(exchangeCurriencesActions.handleFirstSelect(itemValue)),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeContentContainer);
```

And of course I have Provider with store prop

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const store = createStore(exchangeCurriences);
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <StatusBar hidden={true} />
          <MainTabNavigator />
        </NavigationContainer>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

When I pass handleFirstSelect (from mapDispatchToProps) into my component function prop it doesn't work like before. Anyone know where is mistake? Any help with the solution will be appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line looks odd:

```
[action.itemValue]: state.base[action.itemValue]
```

You initialised state.base to 'EUR' a single string and not an array like you have in the reducer code above.

From your original code you simply want to set state.base to action.itemValue which has been set in the action handleFirstSelect

Therefore I would expect your reducer code to look like:

```
const exchangeCurriences = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.HANDLE_FIRST_SELECT:
      return {
        ...state,
        base: action.itemValue, // correct this line
        result: null,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
    };
```

Comment: well it still doesn't work :(. Thanks for your answer

Comment: So, in your new code you are no longer using setState, however, your setState has a callback this.calculate, do you not need to call this functionality elsewhere?

For example perform the same logic in the action handleFirstSelect before returning...

Comment: well, this functions just gives me some console.log() informations

Comment: Where are you checking the results? The results should be in the props object, for example props.baseCurrency

Comment: Results are in Picker component <PickerComponent
              selectedValue={base}
              onValueChange={this.props.handleFirstSelect}
            />

Comment: where are you setting the value of base?

I would expect code like:

const base = this.props.baseCurrency;

Comment: I destructing my state like this const {base, amount, convertTo, result, date} = this.state;  and my initial value is base='EUR'

Comment: OK there is your issue.  MapStateToProps maps the redux 'state' to the 'props' of the class NOT the 'state'.  Also your state seems to have the property baseCurrency, which is fine but you could rename this to 'base' if you like.  Or just do this: const base = this.props.baseCurrency
So any state you have moved from the react class state to redux, will now be available through the props and of course you should remove it from the class state as you have probably already done.

Comment: Oh but if you call this.props.handleFirstSelect() like that then it doesnt get any parameters right?

Comment: Would you not need somthing like onChangeText={ (value) => this.props.handleFirstSelect(value)}  which I thought woudl have been the same as your current code...

Comment: I fiiguret it out. Works perfectly. Thanks Michael !

Answer (score 1):

```
    ...state,
    [action.itemValue]: state.base[action.itemValue], <--- oops previous type here?
    result: null,
```